# Differences between listing particles と, や and に

Tags: grammar

Consider the following:

- A, B and C came:

  1. AとBとCが来た
  2. AやBやCが来た
  3. AにBにCが来た

**What do I need to consider when deciding which of the three (と, や, に) to use?**

I think a large portion is determined by the type of verb used. I shall generalise into two groups:

1. Reciprocal type - marry; meet; be similar
2. Non-reciprocal type - see; walk; be interesting

Ambiguity may result from using listing particles with reciprocal type verbs:

- AとBが結婚した (Ambiguous)

  - A and B got married (to each other)
  - A and B got married (independent instances)
- AやBが結婚した (Not ambiguous)

  - A and B got married (independent instances among others (example-giving nuance of や))

But for these cases:

- AにBが結婚した
- AにBが会った

Can they receive listing interpretation similar to AにBにCが来た?
Will に be forced to be dative?

How about when the sentence is rearranged to:

- BがAに結婚した
- BがAに会った

Can this receive a listing interpretation?
Will に be forced to be dative?

Comment: I don't think AにBにCが来た is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be very little discussion of the usage of に in a list, at least that I can find.  [One paper I found](http://www.lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/nichigen/menu7_folder/symposium/pdf/1/10.pdf) (pdf) says に is used for an increasing list, as in `1本の大根に2本のにんじん`.  There's also [another paper](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110003227136) that is titled promisingly (about all 3, と, や, and に, in fact), but is apparently behind a pay wall.  (FWIW, I also like sawa's answer.)

Comment: @SomethingJapanese `1本の大根に2本のにんじん、えーと、それからトマトも` (three items) is one continuous expression, I think.　Without `それからトマトも`, I think it degrades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the feeling that `に` under the relevant usage is used adverbially and implies "remembering the item one after another while listing", and I think it requires at least three items. Two is too short for remembering one after another.

> AにBにCが来た
>   ?* AにBが来た
>   　AにBにCが結婚した
>   ?* AにBが結婚した

`結婚する` cannot have a dative argument, and I guess the structure of `AにBにCが結婚する` is `Aに[Bに[Cが結婚する]]` "C will get married, in addition to B, in addition to A", rather than `[AにBにCが]結婚する`, so it cannot have the reciprocal interpretation. `BがAに結婚した` is completely ungrammatical.

If you wanted to do a listing interpretation for `会う`, which takes a dative argument, then you can do this:

> AにBに(それに)CがDに会った (A, B: listing interpretation, D: dative)
>   'A, and B, and also C, met D'
>   AがBにCに(それに)Dに会った　(B, C: listing interpretation, D: dative)
>   'A met B, and C, and also D'

Comment: The examples for definition 4 (並助, at the bottom) of the [goo entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/166083/m0u/%E3%81%AB/) for に would suggest that two items (AにB) can be sufficient.

Comment: @SomethingJapanese What I meant was for the listing interpretation of the 並立助詞. For paring interpretations, two is suffient: `豚に真珠`, which I think is close to dative usage. In your link definition 4, the first one has three items. Then there are paring ones, and finally a classical one, which is irrelevant for present Japanese.

Comment: I edited to include 会う in the question (because it can take a dative argument and would be a better candidate for comparing).

Comment: @Flaw I edited.