# Problems with elements of this sentence

Tags: grammar

For full context, see this document:
https://www.docdroid.net/CAEv4Gb/img-20170726-0001-new.pdf

The sentence in question:
赤と白のしまのセーターにジーンズをはいた女の子ですね。

1) Is it necessary to write い-adjective + の here, or would 赤くて白い work as well?
Is there a difference in meaning?

2) why is there this に? I can’t make any sense of it. To me the sentence says: „It is a girl wearing jeans and a sweatshirt in red and white stripes.”
What function does に have in this context? Oo

Comment: That 「に」 has been discussed multiple times here.

Comment: @l'électeur Can you post the link for him here I cant find it.

Comment: @l'électeur How do you propose the OP find such discussions?  A search on に, for example, will pull up just about every post on this site.  I believe I've seen such answers too, but I don't have the slightest clue of how to locate them.  If you have some suggestions to the OP about how they might conduct their search, drop them a clue.  Or better yet, if you know of such answers, create a link.

Comment: It looks like you've got the basic idea.  In this context, に essentially means something like "together with":  so "jeans together with a .... striped sweater".  (Or as you translated it, "and").  But, I can't explain this point of grammar, so I'm not qualified to provide an answer.  I certainly can't explain it enough so that you would be able reproduce such a grammatical construction on your own.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help you [why に can mean “and”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49038/4875)

Answer (score 2):

Ｑ１）

No it is not necessary but still acceptable, but in that case the の in  赤と白**の**[縞]{しま} is needed to be dropped as well.

Acceptable forms:

- 赤と白の縞
- 赤いと白い縞
- 赤と白縞

*Although it maybe valid in some cases, 白い**の**縞　is just **very** weird.  I would suggest **NOT** to say it that way.*

---

Ｑ２）

It can also mean "with".

*Please refer to [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/why-%E3%81%AB-can-mean-and) question*

-A.Ellett

Comment: @A.Ellett  False, I can find it but I just didn't.  l'électeur is a experienced user and I trusted him.  Besides, I did read the same question at least twice before.  I thought if I answered his question 2, it will become a duplicate.

Comment: I was only saying you couldn't find it because that's what you wrote in your comment.  Nevertheless, I wouldn't just take someone's word for it; experienced users can be wrong about what they remember seeing.  I've seen it happen before.  Anyhow, I found the link, perhaps you can embed it as part of your answer.  Just see my comments above.  :-)  Additionally, I think duplicates of this sort of thing are not bad, it will help people in the future with their searches.

Comment: I see, thanks for telling me.  I am new to the site as well anyway. ^_^

Comment: But to be honest I just searched "use of に" and multiple answer shows up even excluding this site.

Comment: 「赤いと白い縞」「赤と白縞」とは言いません。変です。「赤と白の縞」stripes of red and while, 赤(noun)+と+白(noun)+の+縞(noun) としか言わないと思います

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ 確かに変だと思う。でもこう使っている人もあるそうです。

Comment: 日本語母語話者が？ないないｗ　そもそも文法的に間違ってるでしょ、　「 **赤いと**白い縞」とか。ネットでヒットする「赤と白縞」は「赤と白、縞模様の・・・」とかそんな文脈。

Comment: あっそうですね、考えなっかた。
グッグルでヒットしたサイトがあるので（[「赤いと白い縞」](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22%E8%B5%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E7%99%BD%E3%81%84%E7%B8%9E%22)・[「赤と白縞」](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q="赤と白縞") ）考えずにボタンを押したごめん。

Comment: いや、恥ずかしいです。ちゃんと見ていたら自動翻訳を使ったサイトらしいです。

Comment: Thanks!
Why wouldn't 赤くて白い X work btw.?
I once learned that い-adjective くて is a suitable form to chain multiple adjectives?

Comment: Yes it work as well.  And after our discussion, only 赤と白の縞 is acceptable.