# How to interpret this sentence in context of the picture above?

Tags: grammar

First, I'm sorry for the very unspecific topic of this question, but I didn't really know how else to describe my problem.

The sentence in question:
壁には植物が装飾され、都心とは思えないほど緑があふれるチャペルに、床にはじゅうたんではなく木目のフローリングが敷かれた披露宴会場。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/business_tokushu/2018_0621.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004

And the "picture above" (just to explicitly reference it): 
[image]

My attempt at translation:
"About the walls, they are in the chapel where plants are used as decoration and the green overflows to the extent that you can't assess it as city centre and about the floor, it is a presentation banquet hall where there is no carpet rug and wooden floor is spread out."

In general I'm always having some difficulties interpreting sentences which are contextualized by pictures. In this case, the referenced picture seems to show rooms for marriage ceremonies, consisting of a chapel for the ceremony and a banquet hall for the subsequent celebration.

I interpreted this sentence as if there were actually two sentences, each marked by the respective topics 壁には and 床には. 
The problem is that these two sentences seem to reference two different rooms, chapel and banquet hall, but the topics are "floor" and "wall" which are somewhat unspecific considering the pictures. There are floors and walls on both pictures after all :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is introducing two different halls, "the chapel with plants on walls" and "the reception hall with wooden floor".

You're interpreting this two は as topic markers ("about the wall ..."), but I think these two は are contrast markers. Obviously the sentence is talking about two interesting halls, not about walls or floors themselves. These は are making the contrast between a hall characterized by its *walls* and another hall characterized by its *floor*. When you translate this sentence, it should look simply like "(There is) a chapel (with characteristic walls), and (there is) a reception hall (with a characteristic floor)." (FWIW, the floor of a classical 披露宴会場 is usually covered with carpet.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this sentence can be interpreted even without the picture, although it does help visualizing the description.

You kind of skipped `に` after `チャペル` but it's somewhat important here IMO; it's used as ["and" where the two parts are somehow connected or belong together](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/49043/3295). So the full sentence describes both the chapel (concentrating on the walls decorated with greenery) and the banquet hall (where it brings to our attention the floor). Although `には` sets the topic to walls/floor, in fact it's just a set up for describing the room (chapel and banquet hall).
I think it is repeated in the two parts to give a kind of juxtaposition of the two rooms' features.

I would probably translate the full sentence like this:

"In the chapel, the walls are overflowing with green plants to the extent that one may forget being in the city, while in the banquet/reception hall the wooden flooring is laid out instead of carpets".

P.S. to understand the structure of the sentences a little better, it may be useful to shuffle the words around a bit, e.g.

植物が(**壁には装飾され**)、([都心とは思えないほど]**緑があふれる**)チャペル

i.e. plants **decorate the walls** while **greenery overflows**[to the extent one doesn't feel like being in a city], and both parts describe the chapel.