# What is the function of the particle に in this context?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

What is the function of the particle に in this context?

https://streamable.com/wnti04

more specifically in the part that he says:

> 着替え**に** 洗面道具

> お茶セット**に** お皿

> 人形**に** 花瓶

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Particle に to enumerate things / to list items?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12188/particle-%e3%81%ab-to-enumerate-things-to-list-items)

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/49038