# Can 〜に modify a noun?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

Here is an example sentence from a grammar book.

> 東京で若者の街と言ったら、そりゃあ渋谷に原宿だろう。

Does 渋谷に modify 原宿? Can one use 「AにB」in this way to mean “B which is in A”? Or is 渋谷に原宿 simply an abbreviation of 渋谷にある原宿?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49038/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12188/9831

Comment: People believe 渋谷 and 原宿 are different spots and neither contains the other. (They are next to each other, and 原宿 is in 渋谷**区**, though.)